# How to replicate SPSS recode function in R?

Tags: r, spss

Aim is to simulate the SPSS recode procedure in R. The copy-command is hard to translate.

In SPSS I have code as

```
RECODE A (1,2 = 1) (3,4 = copy) (8 thru hi = 3) (else = 1) into B.
```

Applied over A which looks like

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8,9)
```

i get the following (SPSS) result:

```
A = 1,1,3,4,1,1,1,3,3
```

In R a similar code would look like this:

```
B <- Recode(A, recodes = ("c(1,2) = 1; c(3,4) = c(3,4); c(8,9) = 3; else = 1"), as.numeric.result = TRUE)

A = 1,1,3,4,1,1,1,3,3
```

The general Problem is to indicate the Values in the SPSS-copy statement. Here I wrote c(3,4) = c(3,4) - of course, it doesn´t work.

In SPSS also exists the possibility to say else = copy what returns the same output as R do.

Does anyone have a R function that works in the same way as SPSS?

Answer (score 2):

use the `levels` function.  Here's and example with a built in data set:

```
InsectSprays
levels(InsectSprays$spray)<-list(new1=c("A","C"),YEPS=c("B","D","E"),LASTLY="F") 
InsectSprays
```

use this to reset the data set:

```
InsectSprays <- datasets::InsectSprays
```

Comment: Sorry, the question was not formulatet properly

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `ifelse` and `car::recode` to achieve the result you want.

```
library(car)
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8,9)
B <- ifelse(A %in% c(3,4), A, recode(A, "c(1,2) = 1; 8:hi = 3; else = 1"))
cbind(A, B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the `car` package. Unfortunately, there is no "copy" functionality available.

```
library(car)
?recode
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8,9)
B <- recode(A, "c(1,2) = 1; 3 = 3; 4 = 4; 8:hi = 3; else = 1")
B

## SPSS result: A = 1,1,3,4,1,1,1,3,3
## > B
## [1] 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 3 3
## >
```

Comment: Exactly this is the problem. For integers as 3 and 4 the recode translation to R is no problem. If I have a scope of non integer values the problem occurs.

Comment: @diegoal Not sure that I get what you mean. Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(expss)
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8,9)
# '%into%' supports multi-value assignment, eg: ... %into% (a1 %to% a3)
recode(a, 1:2 ~ 1, 3:4 ~ copy, 8 %thru% hi ~ 3, other ~ 1) %into% b
b
# 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 3 3
```

or, with standard R assignment:

```
b = recode(a, 1:2 ~ 1, 3:4 ~ copy, 8 %thru% hi ~ 3, other ~ 1)
b
# 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 3 3
```